# AdMob в приложении

Tags: android, admob

Добавляю рекламу в приложение в Android Studio по этой [инструкции](http://floppyy.ru/2016/04/20/android_admob). В виртуальном устройстве появился рекламный блок с надписью типа тестовый баннер. По [сылке](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start?hl=ru) описано что нужно добавлять строки:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1' 
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
```

Скажите обязательно ли это делать или можно не добавлять?

Answer (score 1):

Добавление FireBase необязательно. Но оно даст вам возможность получать разнообразную инфу о юзерах в консоли. Например кол-во юзеров, их пол, возраст, удержание и оценивать доход от рекламы на одного юзера. Т.е. это полезно, а настраивается очень просто. Вывод - почему бы и не поставить